# Rails NoMethodError in Application#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass' error in a Rails project.

The error comes from the following line in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I have tried remove that line, and the error disappears but javascript files cannot be loaded.

I am using rails 4.2.4 and have been developing this project for a few weeks and this is the first time that I encounter this error. The server worked properly two days agao. The file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` was not changed at all.

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-11-05 17:08:04 +0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
  Rendered application/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 842ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Guildmasters</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1282808844249308017_70187111969200'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (11.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (56.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (42.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (91.5ms)
```

Comment: Can you provide the url you have been triggered?

Comment: Hi, it is the [http://localhost:3000/](http://localhost:3000/)

Comment: Ok, I think you should post the root url of your routes. I don't think that there is no running or calling an object in your application controller.

Comment: Can you post your log? It's likely an environment issue rather than a code one

Comment: I tried change to "defaults", then the javascript files were not included

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figured out the error. I was using EmberJS, and I put a hbs file in the `views` folder, which is supposed to be in the `templates`. After I moved the hbs file, the error disappeared.